# PermissionError using google cloud Vision Api in Firebase Functions in nodejs

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-vision

I have a firebase function and I tried to use Vision API in my firebase function, but I get this error when serve locally

> PERMISSION_DENIED: Cloud Vision API has not been used in project 563584335869 before or it is disabled.
>   Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/vision.googleapis.com/overview?project=563584335869 then retry. If you enabled this API recently

First of all, I don't know where  `563584335869` comes from, since when I click on the link it's not a valid project 
[image]

Second, I select the project and enabled Vision API on it, still getting same error

the code is very straight forward, anyway I add it here

```js
    async analyze(imageStorageLocation: string): Promise<any> {
        const vision = require('@google-cloud/vision');

        const client = new vision.ImageAnnotatorClient();

        const [result] = await client.textDetection(imageStorageLocation);
        const detections = result.textAnnotations;
        console.log('Text:');
        detections.forEach((text: string) => console.log(text));
    }
```

ange this is how I initialized firebase admin
`admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);`

and here is the `package.json`

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/vision": "^1.7.1",
    "@nestjs/common": "^6.0.0",
    "@nestjs/core": "^6.0.0",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^6.9.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "firebase-admin": "^8.7.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.3.0",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.27",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.12",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.2",
    "rxjs": "^6.3.3"
  },
```

### Update

This is how google cloud dashboard looks like
[image]

### Update

I found projectId of my project, which is different than the id in the error message
[image]

### Update

I checked id of all other projects that I have, the number doesn't match to any

### Update

The issue only happens on my local, when deployed to firebase it works

Comment: Hello, 12 digit the number is the number project. If yo go to the main dashboard in the project info you will see your project number. Regarding to the cloud vision api issue give it few minutes after enabling the API and retry

Comment: @Chris32 the project id in the error and actual project id are different

Comment: Just to know were to start. Did you followed this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/before-you-begin)
?

Comment: This error that you are getting is most likely because you dont have your key.json file with your code at the moment of the deployment but I want to confirm if you checked this before. You can forget the project number displayed in the error since seems to be a "harcoded" number in the error message

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks @Chris32, I found the solution based on his lead in the comments.

Since the issue was only on my local serve and it was OK on deployment I did this to solve the issue (https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/before-you-begin)

1. exported a service key file
2. create a environment variable (win 10) named `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`
3. set the path of service key file to this env variable
4. run functions locally

p.s
Surprisingly as Chris mentioned the project id in the error is hard coded and so misleading